# Remote Debug Azure Webrole Entrypoint in VS2013

Tags: azure, remote-debugging, visual-studio-2013, webrole

I'm trying to debug the OnStart in the RoleEntryPoint by just hitting a breakpoint. In Visual Studio 2013 I have managed to do remote debugging on my Azure cloud service, but the entrypoint is kind of hard to hit since it is executed while starting and stopping the service (IE. re deploying the WebRole)

Is this possible, and how?